# (Spring) Issue with java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource cannot be opened because it does not exist

Tags: java, spring

I want to pick up a property file app.properties NOT from the class path resource.
The reason is I am using maven to build a jar file. The jar file is picking up properties from inside the jar. So, others cannot change the property files.

I want the property file to be configurable.

```
<bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>app.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

works fine but

```
<bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>"C:\\Temp\\app.properties"</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

does not work.

Is it possible to place property files in the target folder so the jar can pick it up from outside the jar?

Comment: Im not sure, but do you need the double backslash when specifying the pathname?  C:\\Temp\\app......

Comment: yeah I tried that too. Same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with

```
<property name="location"><value>file:C:/Temp/app.properties</value></property>
```

Comment: I just tried to edit this when I didn't mean too. best reject it